# Как открыть create-react-app на другом компьютере в сети?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

После команды npm start запускается проект. Через ipconfig узнаю свой ip. Получается ссылка вида http://10.0.2.61:3000/ , но на других ПК ничего не отображается. Ниже package.json

```
{
  "name": "prt-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "devextreme": "19.2.3",
    "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery": "^2.7.2",
    "devextreme-react": "19.2.3",
    "formatcoords": "^1.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-treelist": "^1.2.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.2",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.2",
    "react-virtualized-tree": "^3.4.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "react-window-infinite-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.24.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.4",
    "fetch-mock": "^8.2.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.5",
    "json-schema-generator": "^2.0.6",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.1.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^3.5.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo)

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start
```

в вашем случае достаточно

```
HOST=10.0.2.61 npm run start
```

подробнее в [документации](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md)

либо изменить package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "HOST=10.0.2.61 react-scripts start",
   .....
}
```

Comment: Ошибка:  "HOST" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-test@0.1.0 start: `HOST=10.0.2.61 react-scripts start`

Answer (score 0):

В итоге помогло отключение брандмауэра